# manipulating Material-UI with a .css file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, design-patterns, material-ui

Is there any way to customize Material-UI elements with CSS sheets?

I mean, I know about the {makeStyles} method and overriding with JSS, but it looks awful in the code, and moduling it on other arcives gets confusing, I was wondering if there is any workaround to put it all together in a css archive of sorts.

Comment: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#with-material-ui-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your `makeStyles` code on a separate JS file. You would typically store the object it returns in a hook called `useStyles` (this is what you export), and at that point you can use the hook in the relevant components.

However, If you must use raw CSS to customize your MUI components and have those custom CSS prioritized, you can opt to [reorder where the MUI stylesheet is injected](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order)

> The StylesProvider component has an injectFirst prop to inject the
> style tags first in the head (less priority)
>
> ```
> import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
>
> <StylesProvider injectFirst>
>   {/* Your component tree. */}
> </StylesProvider>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

LOL I just needed some more specific Google-fu

This is how I solved it:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { StylesProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import App from './App';
import './GlobalCSS.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StylesProvider injectFirst>
      <App />
    </StylesProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The point is adding the  tag inside your  tag in index.js, and pointing your css in that same file, now you can use the predefined class names or override your class name.